# BindingResult doesn't work after change ModelAttribute name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When using default ObjectName like this:

```
model.addAttribute(myObject);
```

BindingResult will bind the error result to the corresponding input path, with its object name as myObject.

But if I'm using a new name for my object like this:

```
model.addAttribute("newObjectName",myObject);
```

BindingResult will still set its object name as myObject, rather than "newObjectName", and the result error won't be binded.

So, is there any way to make BindingResult work without changing model object name to default?

**My Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="unit/unitAdd.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public final String saveUnitAdd(@Valid PmiUnit pmiUnit,Model model,BindingResult bindingResult,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpSession session){
    logger.info("saveAddUnit called!");
    boolean exists = unitService.isAlreadyExists("pmi_units",   "uni_unit_name_pk",pmiUnit.getUniUnitNamePk());
    if (exists) {
        //exists and without state DEL, return exists error
        logger.info("Unit Name_PK exists");
        if(!unitService.isExistsAndDeleted("pmi_units", "uni_unit_name_pk",pmiUnit.getUniUnitNamePk())){
            System.out.println("exists and not deleted");
            bindingResult.rejectValue("uniUnitNamePk", "pmi.validator.constraints.unique");}
        //exists but with state DEL, update this row
        else{
            unitService.updateDeletedUnit(pmiUnit);
            mainService.getDefaultPmiUnit(pmiUnit, model);
            httpServletRequest.setAttribute("fromAddUnit", "true");
            httpServletRequest.setAttribute("addResult", "true");
            model.addAttribute("pmiUnit",pmiUnit);
            return "accessControl1/unit/unitManage";
        }
    }
    //if has errors, return the same page
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("pmiUnit",pmiUnit);
        return "accessControl1/unit/unitAdd";
    }
```

**The JSP part**

```
<form:form method="POST" id="pmiAddUnit" name="pmiAddUnit"
            modelAttribute="pmiUnit" enctype="multipart/form-data"
            action="unitAdd.do">
...
<table>
    <tr>
    <td align="left"><form:input id="uniUnitNamePk" name="uniUnitNamePk" path="uniUnitNamePk" class="margin-right-ten" /></td>
    <td align="left"><form:errors class="error" path="uniUnitNamePk" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
...
</form:form>
```

import ******.domain.PmiUnit;
In the domain package, the class name of pmiUnit is PmiUnit.
So if I change the modelAttribute name to "pmiUnitObject".(well, it's just I prefer this way, don't like the fixed default way with an unchangable name. And also, if you add several objects, you should be able to use the bean like `${variableName.propertyName}` in your .jsp)

And I modified like this:

```
model.addAttribute("pmiUnitObject",pmiUnit);
```

This is the variable BindingResult during debug:

..awkward, can't post image....

Anyway,you'll see it's still "pmiUnit" in bindingResult.objectName, and it won't bind the error result to the jsp form:errors tag.

Comment: Post your method signature, also why are you adding the object (again) to the model as it should already be there due to the `@ModelAttribute` annotation.

Comment: Please show the method code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have a model attribute you just happen to have an arbitrary method argument with `@Valid`. Next to that you also have a problem in the ordering of your method arguments. The `BindingResult` must directly follow the argument it applies to, in your case the `PmiUnit` argument. See also [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args) of the reference guide.

```
public final String saveUnitAdd(@Valid PmiUnit pmiUnit,BindingResult bindingResult,,Model modelHttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpSession session){ ... }
```

Next to `@Valid` add `@ModelAttribute` and remove the `model.addAttribute` calls.

```
public final String saveUnitAdd(@Valid @ModelAttribute PmiUnit pmiUnit,BindingResult bindingResult,Model model,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpSession session){ ... }
```

If you want to give it another name include it inside the `@ModelAttribute` annotation. The default is to take the name of the method argument.

```
public final String saveUnitAdd(@Valid @ModelAttribute("your-name-here") PmiUnit pmiUnit,BindingResult bindingResult,Model model,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpSession session){ ... }
```

I would also suggest removing the `HttpServletRequest` parameter and simply add the properties you want to add to the model. I would probably rewrite the method to something like the following (also not sure why you still have the `HttpSession` in there as well?).

```
@RequestMapping(value="unit/unitAdd.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public final String saveUnitAdd(@Valid @ModelAttribute("pmiUnitObject) PmiUnit pmiUnit, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, HttpSession session){
    logger.info("saveAddUnit called!");
    boolean exists = unitService.isAlreadyExists("pmi_units", "uni_unit_name_pk",pmiUnit.getUniUnitNamePk());
    if (exists) {
        //exists and without state DEL, return exists error
        logger.info("Unit Name_PK exists");
        if(!unitService.isExistsAndDeleted("pmi_units", "uni_unit_name_pk",pmiUnit.getUniUnitNamePk())) {
            System.out.println("exists and not deleted");
            bindingResult.rejectValue("uniUnitNamePk", "pmi.validator.constraints.unique");}
            //exists but with state DEL, update this row
        }
    }

    if (!bindingResult.hasErrors() ) {
        unitService.updateDeletedUnit(pmiUnit);
        mainService.getDefaultPmiUnit(pmiUnit, model);
        model.addAttribute("fromAddUnit", "true");
        model.addAttribute("addResult", "true");
        return "accessControl1/unit/unitManage";
    } else {
        return "accessControl1/unit/unitAdd";
    }

}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks.  im so beginner -.- does work.. I should have checked the difference between valid & modelattribute